# How to displace markers at the same position in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I add a **listener** to **google maps** so that When it already has marker at say position x,y then another marker when added to the map to the same location will displace both the new and old markers in the vicinity of x,y so that they dont overlap.

also for e.g. there are 2 markers close but not overlapping, we add a third marker overlapping on of them, then we displace all three to form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: You'd have to look at all of your markers and do the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue also, Diodeus is correct that if you want to actually move one of the markers locations you would have to keep a store of your markers and as you are getting ready to plot check if that specific lat lng has already been plotted, if so at that point you would adjust the lat lng.  The problem I ran into was that then one of your markers is in an incorrect location and/or it is still not viewable depending on the degree of zoom in correlation to the displacement that you add to your lat/lng.

I would recommend looking into marker clustering personally.  This seems to be the route to go in these situations if you don't want to have a marker on your map with the incorrect location and still want the end user to be able to know that their are multiple markers on the same location.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is I dont want clusters, I want all markers to be viewable

Comment: If that is what you want to do then you will have to figure out the correct displacement between the markers that you are plotting at the specific zoom level that you set.  As the markers might be visible at zoom level X, but not zoom levels Y and Z (as you zoom further out).  I am not sure of the entire context of your page, you could be plotting just three at most or you could be plotting 300.  If you are only plotting three it is easy it is when you are plotting more than three you will get yourself in trouble as your displacement between your markers will get huge in order for them to be

Comment: viewable at a large zoom level.  This is exactly the situation I ran into and in my situation I could not have markers present on a map that were the incorrect location.